# How can I write this solution more efficiently?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

```
import random

a = [int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10)]
b = [int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10)]
c = [int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10)]
d = dict()
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    for j in xrange(len(b)):
        for k in xrange(len(c)):
            if (i+j+k == 10):
                d[(i,j,k)] = a[i]+b[j]+c[k]

print max(d.values())
```

that code finds the best triples of elements in `a,b,c` such that maximizes `a[i]+b[j]+b[k]` and `i+j+k=10` holds

Comment: This seems like homework. You can eliminate the inner loop, since for a given `(i, j)` only one `k` is possible. Also, you don't need a dict since you're not using its keys at all - just `yield a[i] + b[j] + c[k]` and call `max` on the resulting generator.

Comment: Why do you need this to be more efficient? It runs in under half a millisecond on my laptop.

Comment: @abarnert change 10 to be 1000000 and see how much time it takes now.

Comment: @0x90: But that's a completely different problem. For example, stop allocating three 1M-element lists and find a way to use iterators instead. Or use numpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, you could change the boundaries of your loops and get rid of the innermost loop:

```
import random
a = [int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10)]
b = [int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10)]
c = [int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10)]
d = dict()
for i in xrange(10):
    for j in xrange(10 - i):
        k = 10 - i - j
        if k < len(c):
            d[(i,j,k)] = a[i]+b[j]+c[k]

print max(d.values())
```

This improves the runtime by a factor of ~4.5:

```
In [2]: %timeit original()
10000 loops, best of 3: 166 us per loop

In [3]: %timeit new()
10000 loops, best of 3: 36.1 us per loop
```

Comment: OK, never mind. I accidentally saved t1 over t2… Anyway, yours is 4.6, HYRY's 9.9, the OP's 17.3.

Comment: Or, with PyPy, yours is 0.88, HYRY's is 0.75, the OP's is 1.07. (As usual when you're dealing with loops of almost nothing, changing implementations helps a lot more than trying to optimize the code…)

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not actually using the `dict`'s keys, you could build and iterate a `list` more quickly. But, since you're not actually doing anything with the values, either, except to call `max`, you can just keep track of the max value as you go along, and not build and iterate *anything*.

Modifying NPE's solution:

```
import random
a = [int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10)]
b = [int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10)]
c = [int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10)]
maxval = 0
for i in xrange(10):
    for j in xrange(10 - i):
        k = 10 - i - j
        if k < len(c):
            val = a[i]+b[j]+c[k]
            if val > maxval:
                maxval = val
print maxval
```

This makes it significantly faster than his version in CPython, but it makes a *huge* difference in PyPy.

```
                 OP    HYRY   NPE    AB
CPython 2.7.2    161.  98.8   46.9   38.0
PyPy 1.9.0       11.8  7.28   7.39   2.46
```

Needless to say, using PyPy instead of CPython in the first place is a much bigger win than any of the micro-optimizations anyone's suggested.

---

For a real problem, where you have 1000000 values instead of 10, this is a terrible way to solve it.

For one thing, you can cut your memory usage (and therefore your paging time, cache hits, etc.) way down just by saving the values as arrays of `int32` values instead of Python `list`s. And once you've done that, you might as well put it in a 1000000x3 `numpy.array`. Then you just need to build a mask array of i+j+k==1000000, apply the mask, and find the max value in it. That moves all your loops into C, and I'm guessing it'll be 10-30x faster. Much more than you're going to get out of micro-optimizations with Python.

But you might want to go the other direction. Do you need the lists to exist at all? If you've got a sequence of data being generated/read/whatever lazily, is there a way to do this without reading the whole thing into memory? It seems like you only need two of the lists in full—and only one if you can control the order the third arrives. In fact, if you can control the order of the third one, you only need to generate/read the first 10% of it.

Comment: Because running on a faster computer would also be "much bigger win" if you only compare raw execution time. NPE's solution improves time complexity, which *is the point of the task*. Using PyPy, numpy, moving code to C are all micro-optimizations without that.

Comment: For a real problem, it is also possible that the length is still 10, but you need to call it 1000000 times.

Comment: If the problem is just to find the maximum this is the best solution so far as complexity of computation is concerned. Creating a dict just to use a max on the values is an overkill. +1 for abarnet. (I'm not sure about the `10-i` limit for the j cicle, though )

Comment: @lqc: So you downvoted it based on one of three auxiliary points, completely ignoring the main point (removing the unnecessary `dict`—which, crucially, removes most of the memory allocation costs) and the other two auxiliary points? OK…

Comment: @EnricoGiampieri: The `10-i` limit for the `j` cycle came from NPE's answer. I guess it might have been clearer if I'd shown (and times) the same transformation with the OP's version and with NPE's version? If you think that's worth adding, let me know and I'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your code in a function will increase variable lookup speed, an you don't need the third loop:

```
import random
def f(random=random.random):
    a = [int(1000*random()) for i in xrange(10)]
    b = [int(1000*random()) for i in xrange(10)]
    c = [int(1000*random()) for i in xrange(10)]
    d = {}
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        for j in xrange(len(b)-i):
            k = 10 - i - j
            if 0 <= k < 10:
                d[i,j,k] = a[i]+b[j]+c[k]
    return max(d.values())
f()
```

and if you only want the max value, you don't need the dict.

Comment: How do you `timeit`? My test is 192us v 119us.

Comment: I do some test, and `random.randint(0, 999)` is slower than `int(1000*random.random())`.

Comment: You really think creating the original arrays is part of the issue?

Comment: The arrays aren't needed either. Just generate an `a`,`b`, or `c` random value when one is needed.

Comment: @martineau: I'm assuming the OP is just using the original arrays to simulate a case where he's got three arrays of real data, and needs to select among them. (It might be helpful if he explained his real problem instead of making us guess…)

Answer (score 0):

I think caching `random.random` lookup can improve the performance dramatically.

```
import random

def f():
    rand = random.random
    a = [int(1000*rand()) for _ in xrange(10)]
    b = [int(1000*rand()) for _ in xrange(10)]
    c = [int(1000*rand()) for _ in xrange(10)]
    d = dict()
    for i in xrange(10):
        for j in xrange(10 - i):
            k = 10 - i - j
            if 0 <= k < 10:
                d[(i,j,k)] = a[i]+b[j]+c[k]

    print max(d.values())

f()
```

Comment: The ``random`` is just to generate example data, it's not part of the "problem".

Comment: @lqc, I mean the attribute lookup `random.random` is quite slow. We dont need to repeat this lookup in loops.

Comment: @nymk: But lqc is saying that we only use `random.random` 3*N times, while the inner-loop code is N^3.

Comment: @abarnert: You are right, but in this case, considering that N is not large, the attribute lookup is probably the bottleneck.

Comment: @nymk: Even if the setup isn't irrelevant (as lqc says, and he's probably right), I suspect the 1000 loops and 1000 `dict` expansions are the bottleneck, not the 30 attribute lookups. And in general, the 1000 loops of actual work take longer than the 30 loops of setup.  In fact, I'd be willing to bet on it. But instead of guessing, let's see what `timeit` says… 5.462 vs. 5.522, so you've saved 1.1%. And of course as N increases, that savings will go down. So, not the bottleneck.

Comment: @abarnert: You are right. It seems that I made a mistake. I can't reproduce the profiling results which led me to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: @abarnert:If we replace `int(1000*random.random())` by `random.randint(0,999)`, the performance will decrease significantly. This demonstrates creating the original arrays could be part of the issue.

Comment: @nymk: OK, so I can see why it would be worth _testing_ to see whether the original arrays are still a bottleneck after fixing that first (`randint` is super-slow) problem. But just _assuming_ it's a bottleneck, and stating without testing that you can "improve the performance dramatically", is a different matter.